# Rails 4 passing attr_accessor in association is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been upgrading my app from rails 3 to rails 4 in which i have a model `user.rb` with associations like

Rails 3:

```
 has_many :accounts, :conditions => proc { "accounts.year_id = #{current_year_id}" }
```

where `current_year_id` is `getter` & `setter` methods of `user` and 
It was working fine since rails 3

In Rails 4, i changed it to:

```
 has_many :accounts, -> { where( year_id: current_year_id ) }
```

now, current_year_id become an `attr_accessor`.

The problem is, it throws `undefined local variable or method 'current_year_id' for                                                    Account::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000011e13438`